# Rendering a background-image for DIV within BODY

Tags: html, css

I have the following styles for my page:

```
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        body {
            background-color: rgb(5, 77, 179);
            text-align: center
        }   
        .contentarea {
            background-image: url('path-to-this-image.png')
        }
        .class {
            background-image: url('path-to-another-image.png')
        }

    </style>
```

There are two DIV tags within the body:

```
<body>
    <div class="contentarea">
    </div>
    <div class="class">
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try to load the page, only a blue background appears. Why is this? I'm using Chrome > v.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
    .contentarea {
        background-image: url('path-to-this-image.png');
        height: Height of image in px; // or 100%
    }
    .class {
        background-image: url('path-to-another-image.png');
        height: Height of image in px; // or100%
    }
```

If you don't have text inside the div you have to give height. Also, don't forgot to add semicolon `;` at the end of css property

Comment: Works with px, but can I use percents also? Tried "100%" but nothing showed up.

Comment: You can. But you'll have to adjust styling...I am not sure what you have it in your css..If you create a fiddle I can show you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous: to make it work with 100% set element property as "display:block;". It should work. So your css can look like this:

```
 body{
    background-color: rgb(5, 77, 179);
    text-align: center
  }
 .contentarea {
    background-image: url('path-to-this-image.png');
    width:100%; /*or whatever*/
    min-height:80%;   /*or whatever*/ 
    display:block;
  }
  .class {
      background-image: url('path-to-another-image.png');
      width:100%; /*or whatever*/
      min-height:80%;   /*or whatever*/ 
      display:block;
  }
```